# Date conversion according to user timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

We are converting database date into required user timezone. But if we format using jodatime in string format we are getting correct date and if we parse string to get date object we are getting wrong time. Here is my code. I tried jodatime parser and java date

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateF = "01/19/2019 at 07:35 PM (UTC)";
        String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy 'at' hh:mm a (zzz)";
        long time = 1603305000;
        String timeZone = "Etc/UTC";
        Locale locale=new Locale("en", "US");
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = null;

        if (locale.equals(Locale.FRENCH)) {
            dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat).withLocale(locale);
        } else {
            dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat).withLocale(null);

        }

        if (true) {
            dateFormatter = dateFormatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone));
        }
        // Old Logic using Java Time
        DateFormat format3 = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, locale);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
        if(true)
            format3.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));

        DateTime jodatime = new DateTime(time);
        try {
            System.out.println(dateFormatter.print(jodatime));
            System.out.println("timezone converted Date : " + format3.parse(dateFormatter.print(jodatime)));

            System.out.println("dateFormatter.parseDateTime converted Date : " + dateFormatter.parseDateTime(dateFormatter.print(jodatime)).toDate());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Correct date in Formatted string `01/19/1970 at 01:21 PM (UTC)`

We are getting a wrong result after parsing
timezone converted Date : `Mon Jan 19 18:51:00 IST 1970`

dateFormatter.parseDateTime converted Date : `Mon Jan 19 18:51:00 IST 1970`

Correct date in Formatted Date : `Mon Jan 19 01:21:00 UTC 1970`

Comment: Why are you using `SimpleDateFormat` when you're using Joda-Time? Why are you using the deprecated Joda-Time, and not the Java Time API?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: According to [Epoch Unix Time Stamp Converter](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) Unix time 1603305000 is equivalent to 10/21/2020 @ 6:30pm (UTC). Are you sure you want 01/19/1970 at 01:21 PM (UTC)?

Comment: Mon Jan 19 18:51:00 IST 1970 agrees with 01/19/1970 at 01:21 PM (UTC). If I assume that IST means India Standard Time (it can have other meanings). Both times you are printing a `java.util.Date` object, and a `Date` object hasn’t got a time zone, so you shouldn’t expect it to be converted to the required user time zone.

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible old classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These have been supplanted entirely by the modern *java.time* classes.

You are also apparently mixing those legacy classes with classes from the *Joda-Time* library. Firstly, that mixing is ill-advised. Secondly, Joda-Time is now in maintenance-mode, with its creators advising migration to *java.time*. Actually, both *Joda-Time* and *java.time* projects are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne, with the first project having been the inspiration and education for the second.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

> We are converting database date

Then avoid all the string manipulations you are doing.

As of JDBC 4.2, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database. For a moment, meaning a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myOffsetDateTime ) ;
```

…and…

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Most databases store moments in UTC. You may want to adjust into a time zone for presentation to users. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Generate text in a certain format by using `DateTimeFormatter` object. Either specify a custom formatting pattern or automatically localize by calling `ofLocalized…` methods.

All of this has been covered many many many times on Stack Overflow already. Search to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).